# Portfolio risk of correlated assets using Mahalanobis distance

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk, statistics, value-at-risk, modern-portfolio-theory

I am trying to understand if there is an agreed methodology to measure the total risk in a portfolio of correlated assets.

I am taking a simple model of stock prices following geometric Brownian motion. As I understand it, we may describe the correlation between stock prices via the covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume:

- We hold a portfolio of $n$ assets with weights $\textbf{w}$ and drifts $\mu$
- Asset prices $S_i$ evolve following the SDE:

$$ \frac{dS_i}{S_i} = \mu_i \cdot dt + \sigma_i \cdot dW{_t}{_i} $$

- Log-returns for each asset follow $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2_i)$
- The portfolio log-returns hence follow a multivariate Normal distribution whose shape depends on $\Sigma$

Now, I have commonly seen the portfolio risk described as:

$$ \sigma_p = \sqrt{\textbf{w}^{\top} \Sigma \textbf{w}} $$

It seems to me that the correct metric to use in this case is actually the Mahalanobis distance:

$$ \sigma_p^M = \sqrt{(\textbf{w} - \mu)^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} (\textbf{w} - \mu)} $$

which generalises the Z-score, and which is (for example) relevant to the VaR approach to modelling risk. In this way one can describe the probability distribution of all portfolio values as some function of ($\textbf{w}$, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$)

My questions:

- Is the above reasoning valid, or have I made a mistake?
- If the above is valid, it seems that one method can be substituted for another. What are the implications of doing this?

Bonus question:

- What is the shape of the function which describes the probability distribution of portfolio values in terms of ($\textbf{w}$, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$)?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I thought the use of the Mahalanobis distance is quite interesting for the sake of comparing normalized risk amongst different portfolios. Commenting to bump up this post for an expert to weigh in with his/her opinion.

Comment: Years ago there was an article by Kritzman with a silly title that used the Mahalanobis distance to study the effect of financial crises on security returns. I thought it was interesting. In case it gives you some ideas the paper is https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2469/faj.v66.n5.3